# Scrape PowerBI table using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm pretty new to BeautifulSoup and I'm trying to scrape covid-19 data from a PowerBI table. There are attributes such as svg and tspan, and when I try to print them out, nothing is returned. The goal is to scrape the total number of covid cases in the city from the 2nd of the 3 charts. Any help would be appreciated.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

result = requests.get("https://data.sfgov.org/stories/s/COVID-19-Cases-and-Deaths/dak2-gvuj/")

src = result.content


soup = BeautifulSoup(src, 'lxml')

elements = soup.find_all("tspan")
print(elements)
print("\n")
```

Comment: Is there any reason against using the respective 'Source data' (linked in the report)?

Comment: I’m just trying to find a way to automate this task since I have to do it frequently and for other sites that also use Power BI.

Comment: Power BI will not always expose source data/unencrypted - often it is "securely" tucked away server side.

Comment: In this instance I see the data along with timestamp (first 10 char needed) coming from POST requests for latest data to `https://wabi-us-gov-iowa-api.analysis.usgovcloudapi.net/public/reports/querydata?synchronous=true`

Comment: It is via a [government cloud instance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/admin/service-govus-overview) so check T&C